# Mongoexport specific fields Problem with json

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a DUMP (146k documents) of Geonames in my MongoDB (DB name : db_Name)

Here is the schema :
[image]

I want to export some fields only to json :

```
fields.name, 
fields.country, 
fields.alternate_names, 
fields.latitude,
fields.longitude, 
fields.ascii_name, 
fields.country_code,
fields.timezone
```

So Here is the Code :

```
mongoexport -d db_name -c cities -f 'fields.name,fields.country,fields.alternate_names,fields.latitude,fields.longitude,fields.ascii_name,fields.country_code,fields.timezone' -o c:\DUMP.json
```

But it export all fields, not the specific.

What is wrong in my command ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after searching during days :

You CAN'T export nested fields only in JSON export Mode.

You have to export and import CSV

here is the command :

```
 mongoexport -d db_name -c cities -f 'fields.name,fields.country,fields.alternate_names,fields.latitude,fields.longitude,fields.ascii_name,fields.country_code,fields.timezone' --type=csv -o c:\DUMP.csv

mongoimport -d app -c geoname -f  name,country,alternate_names,latitude,longitude,ascii_name,country_code,timezone --type=csv  c:\dump.csv
```